# How to get a .py file to work on my website in a similar way the command line works - Python/Website

Tags: python, database, web, webserver

I currently have program file, `name.py`, that I am running through the command line. In order to run the file, I am using

```
python3 name.py textdocument.txt "searchTerm1" "searchTerm2"
```

In other words, I am telling the program which text document to reference and then two search terms that the program uses to print a certain string.

**My question is:**
How can I get this on a website and have something like a search box for `searchTerm1` and `searchTerm2` and then hit something along the lines of a search button and have it use my program and text file and print what I would see in the command line - but print it on my website?

The search with `name.py` should be done on the server - only this exact result should be visible on the client.

Comment: This question is unclear - is the python code supposed to be run on the client or server?

Comment: I want someone to visit the website, put in two inputs (the search terms) and then have the website print the output for that client only.

Comment: I added that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set your server up to accept HTTP requests. You can use an [HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) to send a request from the client on your website to the server. Then, use the server to process the request (using that python script you have) and return an HTTP response. [Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is some documentation on a python HTTP library you can use.

You could also set up a database instead of a .txt file to run on your web server, and query it from the client (though that depends on what your script actually looks like).

Comment: please use comments for clarifications